# How to enable multidex(android) in IBM MobileFirst 7.1 Application(Hybrid)

Tags: android, arcgis, ibm-mobilefirst

We are developing a Hybrid Application and have only added necessary libraries to the project. We have the ESRI ArcGIS jars (Native maps) and Pro-guarded version of Google Play Services (to include only Analytics) in the app.
From MobileFirst features, we have JSONStore enabled.

This is resulting in dex issue in Android:
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

ArcGIS recommends not to proguard their already optimized API, in which case we have limited options.

Does anyone know the steps to enable multi-dex in our hybrid app, spl. because we are limited to using Eclipse IDE for MobileFirst app development.

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can think of is to migrate the project to be Gradle-based, by importing the MobileFirst Studio-generated project into Android Studio and select the option to migrate.

Note: MobileFirst Platform Foundation does not support Gradle at this time. This means that after opening the project in Android Studio, if you require any additional changes in the project you will need to build it in MobileFirst Studio and again import and migrate to Gradle and so on on repeat...

Comment: Thanks, that's what we're trying to do now: is to build the multi-dex apk in Android Studio. But are running into issues with the shared libraries not getting into the apk right now. The apk generated using Android Studio doesn't contain 'libs' folder. We can only include required jars as dependencies: something like " compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) ". This won't accept .so extensions, which are needed by JSONStore feature. Would you know how worklight identifies these .so files within the project structure? file path, folder structure etc.

Comment: Idan, we tried the work around you suggested. It did not work. I created a simple hello world program in worklight studio, built and ran successfully in worklight but  when I " Run as android studio", then open in android studio,  it builds successfully there but does not run on any android phone. Since worklight does not support gradle, is there any official documentation on how worklight projects should be built in android studio? This is critical to get around the multidex problem.

Comment: I cannot comment on future plans, but something is being cooked. Anyway, when you open Android Studio it gives an option to import an ADT project. That's what you need to select and it will then attempt to migrate the project to Gradle, you then need to build it and it may give some errors that you need to correct and then it should work. What did you try exactly?

Comment: @IdanAdar is there a way for us to fix this issue in Eclipse itself. Since while migrating to studio induces so many issues where we have the complete project built already?

Comment: Not really. Google itself also stopped supporting Eclipse as IDE... It's time to progress.